# Fixed bottom bar leaves gap below when window is large (responsive design)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am having an issue which I just cannot seem to pinpoint with my code.

My page is located at [seamonkeymedia.co.nz/secondary.php](http://www.seamonkeymedia.co.nz/secondary.php)

The problem seems to only occur when the WINDOW HEIGHT is large, you can try it out by shrinking the height of the page and watching the gap below the navbar disappear.

Essentially I need that bottom bar to be fixed to the bottom of the window - almost like it would if this was an iPad app.

Any suggestions would be helpful. I have been playing around with paddings and margins on all container elements but that shouldn't really be the issue. I am all out of ideas here.

Because I am using boilerplate & respond - it is far easier to view my code in the Browser. Please forgive me if this is an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a height of 15% set on the #footer element. That should be 88px since that's the size of your background image.

Comment: @derek - not sure I'm following that comment.

Comment: I need the footer & images to resize. They do this perfectly fine so I am not seeing how this is an issue - CSS allows the image to resize unless its height is specified in px - which it isn't

Comment: You're correct, my apologies. I changed the background repeat from 'repeat-x' to 'repeat' and that fixed it, however I want the image to rescale height wise. I will work on this but you've solved my problem. Thank you Kai